# Rethinkdb Geospatial: getIntersecting

Tags: geospatial, rethinkdb, rethinkdb-javascript

I have a query that searches through a list of polygons and checks to see if any of a list of points is included. 
My problem is I need to some how insert a indicator of which polygon the point was found in.

Here is my query:

```
function fieldGeoFilteringFn(){
    r.connect(config.rethinkdb, function(err, conn){
        if(err) {
            console.log('conn err', err)
        }
    r.db('queue').table('activeJobs').forEach(function(id) {
        return r.db('queue').table('fieldTrucks').insert( r.db('queue').table('tracksInit').getIntersecting( 
            r.db('queue').table('activeJobs').get(id('id'))('shape')('location') , {index: 'geometry'}).pluck(
                ['Heading', 'MobileName', 'geometry', 'id', 'Speed', 'HardwareId']))  }).run(conn, function(err,result){
                if(err) {
                    console.log("Insert Field Trucks  err", err)
                } else {
                    console.log("Field truck insert")
                }
            })
    })
}
```

The id from each of the activeJobs is what I would like to insert along with the other fields am "plucking".

If more information is needed just let me know.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `merge` to combine objects.

Does this do what you want?

```
r.db('queue').table('activeJobs').forEach(function(job) {
  return r.db('queue').table('fieldTrucks').insert(
    r.db('queue').table('tracksInit').getIntersecting(job('shape')('location')).pluck(
      ['Heading', 'MobileName', 'geometry', 'id', 'Speed', 'HardwareId']).merge(
      {job_id: job('id')}))
})
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. Would I be able to use any of the fields in the job  document? Or would I need to pass it along with the id?

Comment: Nm I understand. Sorry noob mistake